# How to delete a part of from json file golang

Tags: go

Suppose I have such a json file. I want to delete one of the window, image or text fields according to the user's choice and print the rest of the content to a different file.

```
  {
 "window": {
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
},
"image": { 
    "src": "Images/Sun.png",
    "name": "sun1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 250,
    "alignment": "center"
},
"text": {
    "data": "Click Here",
    "size": 36,
    "style": "bold",
    "name": "text1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 100,
    "alignment": "center",
    "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
}
}
```

For example, I want to delete the window field
I want to write this content to a different file.

I'm stuck and have no idea how to do it. It is easy to write to another file, but I have no way of knowing how to delete a fiel

Can you suggest me some approaches that make sense?

```
   {
  "image": { 
    "src": "Images/Sun.png",
    "name": "sun1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 250,
    "alignment": "center"
},
"text": {
    "data": "Click Here",
    "size": 36,
    "style": "bold",
    "name": "text1",
    "hOffset": 250,
    "vOffset": 100,
    "alignment": "center",
    "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, we can follow two approaches here.
First We can Unmarshal `JSON` data into the Go language `struct`
Second, we can Unmarshal`JSON` data into the Go language `map`
because I don't know the struct so we can go with the map.

You can try the first approach also for learning purposes but that will only work with proper struct.

```
data := []byte(`{"window":{"title":"Sample Konfabulator Widget","name":"main_window","width":500,"height":500},"image":{"src":"Images/Sun.png","name":"sun1","hOffset":250,"vOffset":250,"alignment":"center"},"text":{"data":"Click Here","size":36,"style":"bold","name":"text1","hOffset":250,"vOffset":100,"alignment":"center","onMouseUp":"sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"}}`)

var v interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
m := v.(map[string]interface{})
// delete window
delete(m, "window")
```

then you can again marshal to JSON and write to file

```
b, err := json.Marshal(m)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/SBFhH3YbhuJ)

Comment: This is very useful, thank you very much. I was trying to create a struct and parse it to struct type. I didn't understand the interface you used. I think this interface data type replaces a struct. Anyway, I realized that I need to improve on the interfaces on go, thank you very much.